# How to create a function for getting total amount?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

[image]

I want to create a function that get the total amoun of duration for a car/(regNr)

It should take the argument regNr and calculate the amount of duration

So for example ABC123 should get the total duration - 180.

Thanks.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`, use `SUM()`.

Comment: total duration - 180 ? I don't understand.

Comment: @Raptor - ABD123 has 2 entries, 1 for 80, 1 for 100. I'm assuming the "-" was meant to be a separator, not to indicate a negative value..

Comment: XYZ123 us an 11 year old Saab 9-3, does that vehicle really have an auto-pilot?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT regNr, CONCAT('total duration - ', SUM(duration)) AS output FROM table_name
GROUP BY regNr
```

which will output:

```
regNr         output
======================================
ABC123        total duration - 180
DEF456        total duration - 130
```

Comment: Thats exacltý how I want the result to be, but I want to learn how to do this as a function ( CREATE FUNCTION .... ). I'm new to sql and want to see how that whould work.

You should enter the regNr that you want the total duration of.

Comment: That's a totally different question. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html) for syntax.